# Why are mass and other properties not considered dimensions?

Tags: mass, dimensional-analysis

If we had a flat, planar universe, and put it on an x-y graph. Then we considered the mass or energy density at each point to be the z-component of each point, it would be continuous and smooth. It's information that can't be expressed by the other 4 dimensions. So when physicists say they're looking for more dimensions, why can't that be one of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think dimension relies on the context, for instance mass could be a dimension if you consider a function of mass or any other quantity, It's just convention to talk about the three orthonormal vectors $\hat{x} \hat{y} \hat{z}$ and perhaps time as being the dimensions of the space we are working in. But in something like a configuration space the dimensions are conjugate momentum, generalized position etc.